# Error insert_one document pymongo from file csv

Tags: python, mongodb, csv, typeerror, pymongo-3.x

I'm a novice of python and mongodb and I try to write from a cvs file to a pymongo document. The error is as follows: T**ypeError: 'str' object is not callable**
Because? I attach the relevant code
Thanks

```
import csv
import sys
import json
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(host="localhost", port=27017)
db=client["test"]
mycol=["movimenti"]
print(mycol)

with open ('Movimenti.csv','r') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f, delimiter=';')
    next(reader, None)
    data = []


    try:
        for row in reader:
            for col in row:
                mydict = {"datacontabile": col(1), "datavaluta":   col(3),"causale": col(4), "descrizione": col(5), "importo": col(6)  }                x = mycol.insert_one(mydict)
    except csv.Error as e:
        sys.exit('file{} , line{}: {}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error does nos come from pymongo but from trying to call `col` when defining your dictionary. That's because your columns are string:

```
with open('some_csv_file.csv', 'r') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   next(reader, None)

   for row in reader: # each row
       for col in row: #each value in your row
           print(type(col)) #outputs "<class 'str'>"
```

Parenthesis are used for call to functions only. If you want to take the first character of your string, use brackets:

```
s = "Hello world"
print(s[0]) # outputs "H"
print(s(0)) # outputs TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Usually, one line in a csv is one entry in your database. Hence I think your code should be:

```
        for row in reader:
            mydict = {"datacontabile": row[1], "datavaluta":  col[3], "causale": col[4], "descrizione": row[5], "importo": [6]}
```